# populate master table from daily table for updated and new inserted records

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two table which has few records

**name** is the **column** on which I can apply **join condition**

**Table A** master table

```
#+-------------+----------+---------------------------+---------+
#| name        | Value    | date                      |city     |
#+-------------+----------+---------------------------+---------|
#|  RHDM       |    123   |  2-07-2020 12:00:55:842   |New York |
#|  Rohit      |    345   |  1-05-2021 11:50:55:222   |Berlin   |
#|  kerry      |    785   |  3-04-2020 11:60:55:840   |Landon   |
```

I have other table with almost same number of columns but the date and value column get changes daily

**TableB**

```
#+-------------+----------+---------------------------+---------+
#| name        | Value    | date                      |city     |
#+-------------+----------+---------------------------+---------+
#|  Rohit      |    350   |  12-07-2021 12:00:55:842  | Berlin  |        value and date changed
#|  Bob        |    985   |  23-04-2020  10:00:55:842  |India    | new record 
#|  kerry      |    785   |  13-04-2020  12:00:55:842  | Landon  | only date change
```

I need output as Table3 which need to have all records from table A plus update records from table B ,If there is any change in value and date column that has to pick from tableB into table A

```
#+-------------+----------+----------------------------+---------+
#| name        | Value    | date                       |City     |
#+-------------+----------+----------------------------+---------+
#|  RHDM       |    123   |  2-07-2020  12:00:55:842   |New York |
#|  Rohit      |    350   |  12-07-2021 12:00:55:842   |Berlin   |
#|  kerry      |    785   |  13-04-2020 12:00:55:842   |Landon   |
#|  Bob        |    985   |  23-04-2020 10:00:55:842   |India    |
```

In python pandas I would have done by creating two df like dfA,dfB and then

```
result = pd.merge(dfA,dfB,on=['name'],how='outer'indicator=True)
```

and apply further logic , can anyone suggest how to do it in pyspark,spark-sql

Comment: what the wrong in question ? why negative comments

Comment: The problem is that you keep changing the question and the use case all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a join :

```py
from pysql.sql import functions as F

df3 = dfA.join(
    dfB,
    on="name",
    how="full",  # Or "outer", same thing
).select(
    F.col("name"),
    F.coalesce(dfB["Value"], dfA["Value"]).alias("Value"),
    F.coalesce(dfB["date"], dfA["date"]).alias("date"),
)

df3.show()
+-----+-----+----------+                                                        
| name|Value|      date|
+-----+-----+----------+
|kerry|  785|13-04-2020|
|  Bob|  985|23-04-2020|
| RHDM|  123| 2-07-2020|
|Rohit|  350|12-07-2021|
+-----+-----+----------+
```

Comment: I am trying to 
.select( F.col("name"), F.col("City"),
    F.coalesce(dfB["Value"], dfA["Value"]).alias("Value"),
    F.coalesce(dfB["date"], dfA["date"]).alias("date"),
)but getting spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'City' is ambiguous

Comment: @punm For each column other than "name" which exists in both dataframe, you have to write the `coalesce`. Just reproduce what is made for value or date.

Comment: I am able to get the result partially  but if the date become with timestamp then it create a issue , I am always getting  date with current time stamp.

Comment: @punm Please add [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @punm There is no reason any current timestamp spontanously appears in your data.